# meteor android sdk, is it possible to install on ubuntu vm (virtualbox) or windows

Tags: android, ubuntu, meteor, sdk, virtualbox

Is it possible to install the meteor sdk for android in an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VM (VirtualBox)?

Scenario: I set an Ubuntu VM for meteor development (host OS Windows 8.1). I wanted to try the Meteor app build for Android but when I try to install the Android SDK it fails.

As I understand it the SDK wants to use KVM for the emulator. /dev/kvm does not exist and as the VM is running on VirtualBox I understand it's not possible to run kvm in the VM (even ignoring the performance problems).

I installed the Google Studio and Android SDK but meteor seemed to ignore that.

Abandoning that approach I switched to run Meteor on the native Windows OS but to date the Android SDK is not available for windows, so was thwarted again.

Does the SDK only install on a Native Linux OS (not virtualised)?

I'd appreciate any tips if anyone had the Meteor SDK running on a Linux VM. Thanks

Comment: I tried on VM aswell but from what I know VM doesn't support some kind of rendering that Android SDK requires to run smooth, so you will be able to start it but lags will drive you crazy, better just to install some Linux distribution as your secondary OS and do it there. That's my solution, maybe I missed something and you are able to develop Android app on VM

Comment: I could not get the install to work (did not get past trying to install the sdk) so in the end built Ubuntu/Meteor on a USB stick and all runs fine from there. Thanks Sindis.

Answer (score 0):

Yep it works, running `meteor install-sdk android`, `meteor add-platform android`, and then `meteor run android` should fire up an emulator.

Comment: Could not get past the meteor install-sdk android. It kept failing no /dev/kvm.